# how to find identical files by names and at same location in 2 or more directories

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script that can give a list of identical files just by name between 2 or more directory locations

```
diff -srq Ear2.ear/ Ear1.ear/ | grep identical
```

but seems this is comparing contents as well.

I already have a file that has list of all the target directories I need to compare. However, I need to exclude certain sub-directores while comparing.

Comment: Possibly helpful http://superuser.com/questions/228763/how-to-diff-file-names-in-two-directories-without-writing-to-intermediate-files ?

Comment: that where i picked above. i don't know how to exclude some dirs

Comment: To clarify, is the problem with the above command that you don't know how to exclude certain subdirectories? or do you also want it to only compare filenames and not contents?

Comment: both. i need to compare only files names  and i also need to exclude certain sub directories

Comment: You can start with `comm -1 -2 <(ls $1 | sort) <(ls $2 | sort)` to compare two directories (called with `yourscript.sh ./dir1 ./dir2`)

Answer (score 0):

This takes advantage of the `find` utility's `-prune` option to exclude directories:

```
comm -1 -2 <(cd $1; find . -name "*" -path "./folder1" -prune -o -print | sort) <(cd $2; find . -name "*" -path "./folder1" -prune -o -print | sort)
```

1. `cd` so that we don't include the parent directory in the output of `find`.
2. Run `find` with appropriate parameters to print all files, excluding given subfolders.
3. Pipe that into `sort`, so that we can
4. Use the `comm` utility via process substitution to show only the lines (aka file names) in common.

**Basic Example:**

I have the folder structure:

```
diffdir1/
  file1.txt
  file2.txt
  uniqueTo1.txt
  folder1/
    file1.txt
    folder2/
       file1.txt
  folderUniqueTo1/
    file1.txt

diffdir2/
  file1.txt
  file2.txt
  uniqueTo2.txt
  folder1/
    file1.txt
  folder2/
    file1.txt
```

(Contents do differ between the various `file1.txt`s, although that's not checked here.) Using the above script, I get:

```
$ ./script.sh diffdir1 diffdir2
.
./file1.txt
./file2.txt
```

aka only the two files with the same names.

As a sanity check, if I remove the `-path "./folder1" -prune -o -print` part of the command, this should no longer exclude things under `folder1`:

```
$ ./script2.sh diffdir1 diffdir2
.
./file1.txt
./file2.txt
./folder1
./folder1/file1.txt
```

Using a file for the list of directories and such would just be a matter of modifying what goes into the different parameters of the `find` command.

**Example: Exclude multiple subdirectories**

This command will exclude the folders `./abc/xyz/obj64`, `./abc/video`, and `./sim`:

```
comm -1 -2 <(cd $1; find . -name "*" \( -path "./abc/xyz/obj64" -o -path "./abc/video" -o -path "./sim" \) -prune -o -print | sort) <(cd $2; find . -name "*" \( -path "./abc/xyz/obj64" -o -path "./abc/video" -o -path "./sim" \) -prune -o -print | sort)
```

Note that the list of paths must be placed inside of `\( \)` parenthesis. `-o` means "or", so it's now checking if any of the paths match for pruning.

**Example: Include only files matching a particular pattern**

Expanding off of the previous example, now let's only return files matching a pattern. In this example I'll search for only files ending in `.xml`:

```
comm -1 -2 <(cd $1; find . \( -path "./abc/xyz/obj64" -o -path "./abc/video" -o -path "./sim" \) -prune -o -name "*.xml" -print | sort) <(cd $2; find . \( -path "./abc/xyz/obj64" -o -path "./abc/video" -o -path "./sim" \) -prune -o -name "*.xml" -print | sort)
```

The difference here is that the `-name` argument was moved to *after* pruning. This doesn't make a difference if you are searching for all files (`"*"`), but does matter when you have a pattern. So it's a good idea to put the `-name` at the end anyways in case you might change it later.

Comment: should that be -path or -not -path ?

Comment: It should be `-path`, with the path you want to exclude. I'll add the example directory structure and output I tested with.

Comment: And for more than 2 directories ?

Comment: what -1 and -2 options here?

Comment: @Vik for `comm`, `-1 -2` suppress the output of lines unique to the first and second files, respectively

Comment: @Kenavoz, my understanding is that you would have to put a `-path abc -o -path def ...` for each path you want to exclude. I'm not a `find` expert though so there may be a cleaner way that I'm overlooking. I also just found [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73938/passing-multiple-directories-to-the-prune-option-in-find) which has some alternatives.

Comment: i did *.xml instead of * in find but i see in results/. why?

./lib/adf-loc.jar

and using moe -path "pattern" is the correct way to exclude more than one sub directories?

Comment: To diff only particular file patterns, an easy fix would be to pipe the final output through grep, e.g. `comm ... | grep .xml`. Or move the `find` args around like: `find . -path "./folder1" -prune -o -name "*.txt" -print`. I just added an example for that and for multiple subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

An array cross-section would be an interesting way to solve this.

```
$ mkdir tmp1 tmp2
$ touch tmp1/foo tmp1/bar tmp1/baz
$ touch tmp2/foo tmp2/bar tmp2/slurm
$ cd tmp1; a=( * ); cd -
$ cd tmp2; declare -A b; for f in *; do b[$f]=1; done; cd -
$ for x in "${a[@]}"; do [[ "${b[$x]}" ]] && echo "$x"; done
bar
foo
```

However, you mentioned that you "*need to exclude certain sub-directores while comparing*", and your `diff` includes `-r`, so you're looking to be selectively recursive.

To achieve this, I'd suggest using bash's `globstar` and then removing the parts you don't want. For example:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ a=( **/* )
$ for x in "${!a[@]}"; do [[ "${a[$x]}" = tmp3/* ]] && unset a[$x]; done
```

Note that globstar requires bash version 4.